# Stop opening directory path in browser

Tags: excel, windows, firefox, explorer

I generated a list of paths to some server and dumped them into an excel file. Now if I copy paste one of the links from the excel file into the windows explorer search bar, it will always call my browser to open the link, but I want to open it with the associated file type app or, if it is a directory, with the explorer.

Note that the paths lead to a directory on a server. Interestingly the following link will open in the browser //myserver.aa.company.com/some/destination/on/server, while mapping the the server first to a network folder, so that the link looks like G:\some\destination\on\server, works perfectly well.

Tried to look into the file type associations of windows. And folder options of course.

The expected result would be, to be able to open paths leading to a server directory simply in the explorer by copy pasting them into the search bar of the windows 10 explorer. 
Current status is, that the browser tries to open the path with the message "connection failed".

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. One needs to use only '\' in the link.